# How to use a MySQL Query within a PHP function correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, require

So I'm trying to run a MySQL query within a PHP function, and I'm getting an error.

So currently I have this:

```
ob_start();
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'database', '', 'user');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed!';
    exit;
}
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Below that this:

```
require_once('function_x.php');
```

function_x.php contains:

```
function doX($variable) {
    global $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `x` FROM `y` WHERE `z` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $variable);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($db_x);
    if ($stmt->affected_rows = 1) {
       //Do something
    }
}
```

So the page loads with no warnings when this function isn't in use. But if I try using it, e.g. `doX('test')` I get a fatal error saying `'Fatal error: doX(): Cannot write property in ...'` on the line with `if ($stmt->affected_rows = 1) {`.

I can't work out why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: do you need to declare the global variable in the page that includes your function_x.php page?  Wouldn't declaring it a global in an included page result in it not being accessible by the parent? if wrong my apologies haven't done much PHP lately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is for assignment.

`==` is for comparison.

Comment: We've all made that mistake. You were lucky this time, because `affected_rows` is a read-only property of a mysqli statement. Some people develop a habit of putting the constant value on the left, like `if (1 = $stmt->affected_rows)` so if they mistype the operator, they are sure to get an error.